# Upload an Image from SD card to a Lamp Server

Tags: android, upload, httpwebrequest

I am trying to upload an image from the android device to a LAMP server where i will handle the form through PHP.

i have an image view which has been set with the image path from the SD card

i want to upload this image on click of a button

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a link that will guide you

http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html

Comment: Thank you will hav a look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can upload things from Android through POST (and therefore, FILES). Simply send it up to your PHP as a POST (with the "upload" button being the submit), just like you would do a form on a webpage, then write a PHP script to handle saving the file.

Comment: Thanks. basically i want to write a function across the app to handle the uploads and content delivery

Comment: It will probably be good to look into an MVC framework and Object-relational mapper on the PHP side if you aren't already. From there, if the framework doesn't already have one, you can create a generic upload function that determines the model and creates and saves the object accordingly.

Comment: yeah i am using.. cakePHP.. but to test will use php

Comment: but i wanna know how to upload or send the file from android to the server